# System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting Rotate Entire Chart 90 degrees

Tags: charts, visualization

I am using the System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting component to create Charts that are rendered in pdfs. Currently the Chart renders perfectly however I want to display it on the page in landscape i.e. rotate the entire chart 90 degrees.

So after I have created the Chart i want to rotate it 90 degrees?
Is this possible after the Chart has been created or something I have to do when Im creating the chart i.e. rotate all its Y\X axis 90 degrees during creation?

I thought rotating the ChartAreas would be a way to go but this didnt result in the my desired outcome

I also created an image from the Chart then tried rotating the created png image using code below however that resizes image incorrectly i.e. makes it bigger. However ideally I would like to just rotate the original chart rather than go down this route

```
chartImage.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

While still a compromise, you could try another way of forcing the image size to be the same dimensions to get around the resize issue you're facing. Instead of rotating the existing image you could make a new image with the desired dimensions explicitly, and then draw on that from the original. Something like:

```
// load your original, horizontal chart image
var chartImage = Image.FromFile(imagePath);

// make the new rotated chart image with same dimensions as original
var rotatedImage = new Bitmap(chartImage.Height, chartImage.Width);

using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(rotatedImage))
{
    g.TranslateTransform(chartImage.Height, 0);
    g.RotateTransform(90.0F);
    g.DrawImage(chartImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, chartImage.Width, chartImage.Height));
}

// save the rotated image
var rotatedImagePath = "path_to_rotated_image.png";
rotatedImage.Save(rotatedImagePath);

// access the new image for display
```